# How to run a sql script using SQL statements in HyperSQL DB?

Tags: hsqldb, sql-scripts

I have a .sql file and I need to run it using SQL statement in HSQLDB which is similar to H2's `RUNSCRIPT FROM 'abc.sql'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the HSQLDB SQLTool. The link below describes how.

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/util-guide/sqltool-chapt.html#N109EC